# perturbation of the form $W(x) = a\omega_0\delta(x− \frac{a} {2})$ calculate the changes in the energy level of the particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

Consider a particle of mass $m$ in one-dimensional inﬁnite potential well of width $a$, i.e. $V (x) = 0$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ a$, and $V (x) = \infty$ for $x < 0$ and $x > a$.

The particle is subject to perturbation of the form $W(x) = a\omega_0\delta(x−
\frac{a} {2})$ where $\delta(x− \frac{a}{2})$ is the $\delta$-function.

The unperturbed system has the energy eigenvalues and eigenvectors given as

$\phi_0^n(x) =\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$

$E_0^n =\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2n^2} {2ma^2}$.

I want to calculate the changes in the energy level of the particle in the ﬁrst order of $\omega_0$.

I have that:

Taking the 1st order equation, and projecting onto$|\phi_n\rangle$ gives :

$\langle \phi_n|(\hat H_0-\epsilon_0)|1\rangle + \langle \phi_n|(\hat W-\epsilon_1)|\rangle$.

And if I let $|\phi_n\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $\epsilon_0=E_0^n=\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2n^2} {2ma^2}$.

I have that $\epsilon_1=\langle\phi_n|\hat W|\phi_n\rangle$

Leaving me with $E_n(\lambda)=E_n^0+\langle\phi_n| W|\phi_n\rangle+O(\lambda^2)$

And $\lambda\hat W = W$

Which if I correct in what I am doing should give:

$E_n(\lambda)=\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2n^2} {2ma^2}+\langle\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})|a\omega_0\delta(x−
\frac{a} {2})|\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\rangle +O(\lambda^2)$

$E_n(\lambda)=\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2n^2} {2ma^2}+W\langle\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})|\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\rangle +O(\lambda^2)$

$\langle\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})|\sqrt{\frac{2} {a}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\rangle  = 1$

Hence $E_n(\lambda) = \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2n^2} {2ma^2} + a\omega_0\delta(x−
\frac{a} {2})+O(\lambda^2)$

Is my method here correct or am I misunderstanding the question completely. All help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually used the delta function when evaluating your inner product, you've just pulled it out.

Comment: I believe the inner product should be an infinite integral of the wavefunction you have but you must include the delta function in this calculation as stated by @Charlie. $\int^{\infty}_{\infty} \phi_n\delta(x-\frac{a}{2})\phi*_n dx$